# Filtering Object based on contains keyword

Tags: node.js

I need to return all property values that contain ".com" to my object. Currently I can filter based of exact keyword however I'd like to filter by ".com" and return all objects with the value ".com" in them filtering out the rest.

Assume my array looks like this:

```
   [{company: google.com},{company: $500 reward},{company: amazon.com},{company: 
   facebook.com},


    const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const list = [];
    const items = document.querySelectorAll("body > div.js-application-root.full-size > div > 
    main > div > div > div > div > div.content-wrapper.spec-program-contents > div > 
    div.program__profile > ul > li")
    
       for (const name of items) {
        list.push({
        company: name.innerHTML,
       }) 
      }
      return list
     })

     var filter = "company";
     var keyword = ".com";
  
     var filteredArray = data.filter((item) => item[filter] === keyword);
     console.log(filteredArray);

     // jobs.deleteMany({})
     // jobs.insertMany(data)
     console.log(filteredArray)
     await browser.close()
    })()
    }
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
data.filter((item) => item[filter].includes(keyword))
```

You can read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp)